# AttributeError: 'BookForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

Error : AttributeError: 'BookForm' object has no attribute 'get'.
im unable to debug the problem.please be helping out.thanks in advance

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Book

class BookForm(forms.Form):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['title', 'sub_title', 'author', 'image', 'price', 'description', 'ISBN', 'number_of_pages','dimensions', 'interior_pages','binding','availability','genre']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.BookForm, name = 'bookform' ),
]
```

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import BookForm

```
def bookview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.post)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save()
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = BookForm()
        return render(request,'book.html',{'myform':form})
```

template

```
<html>
<head>
<title>edit</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}

<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In url pattern you need to link **views** with url path. But you are using form class here, change `urls.py` to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.bookview, name='bookform'),
]
```

Also to use auto generated fields you need to use `ModelForm` as form's base class:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'sub_title', 'author', 'image', 'price', 'description', 'ISBN', 'number_of_pages','dimensions', 'interior_pages','binding','availability','genre']
```

**UPD**

You have `myform` variable in view's context, so you need to use it in template instead of `form`:

```
{{myform.as_p}}
```

Comment: yeah, i see, i did silly mistakes, i changed url to "views.bookview" and base class to "ModelFrom". but then another problem is arising, on the front end only "OK" button is getting displayed. No form is displaying at all! Now what mistake have i done?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak check updates. You need to change template.

Comment: sir when im trying to hit save button it show this error 
    File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\DjangoStuff\booksell\book\views.py", 
    line 7, in bookview
       form = BookForm(request.post)
    AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'.`

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak it should be POST instead of post: `form = BookForm(request.POST)`